# xcode error when option click on variable

Tags: swift, xcode

Recently, when I `option click` on swift variable names in xcode, I have been receiving this message.

[image]

I have done a search online and nothing really turned up. Could someone please explain the error to me and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restarting `Xcode` and/or your system, [it's a known bug](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/102790).

↳ https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/102790
↳ https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/311390#311390